# How ParseExact know my local TimeZone?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timezone-offset

I use this code to convert my UTC string Time with format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" to date time . for example :

```
string PurchaseDate == "2017-12-12T14:29:26Z";
datetime dt =  DateTime.ParseExact(PurchaseDate , "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", null);
```

i know that PurchaseDate time is UTC time (because of "Z"). dt return {12/12/2017 5:59:26 PM} that it is my local Time(client time zone). in other word DateTime.ParseExact convert PurchaseDate to my client time zone! my question is how this method know my client TimeZone ? is it recommend to use this for global application and show user time zone at all ??

---

Update My question:

sometime for implement timezone management in my global website i google it for possible souloution and I find this Use ful link :

[How to display dates and times in clients timezone](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/how_to_display_dates_and_times_in_clients_timezone)

after month i found we can use TimeZoneInfo.Local for finding cliend TimeZone ! 
so should i say that link is useless? I want to know if there is a simple way to find client time zone in dotNet BackEnd code so why this complex way is Used ??

Comment: Local timezone is available to anyone who wants to get it. See [`TimeZoneInfo.Local`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: You can literally enter DateTime.ParseExact in Google and the first link will get you to MSDN, which will answer your question.

Comment: It uses the culture set into `Application.CurrentCulture` which is by default loaded from windows settings. You can change it whenever you want

Comment: You really need to get your mind around the fact that a `DateTime` object is different from its `string` representation. A `DateTime` is a point in time, and can be referred to in a number of ways.

Comment: Z doesn't affect the way it is parsed, it is just matched as a character.  Use the 4th argument, pass System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... how this method know my client TimeZone?

It doesn't understand anything about a "client".  It just has the local time of wherever the code is running. If the code is running on a user's desktop computer or mobile device, then it's the time zone of that device.

If the code is running on a server, then it uses the time zone of the server.  You should avoid this in general, as the server's time zone is usually irrelevant to your application or users.  This applies to `TimeZoneInfo.Local` as well.

If you want to parse your string as UTC `DateTime`, then you'll need to pass an argument that tells the parser not to convert to local time:

```
string PurchaseDate = "2017-12-12T14:29:26Z";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(PurchaseDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("...you'll need to decide...");
DateTime clientDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, tz);
```

In the above, I use `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind`, which says to evaluate the string for it's offset (`Z` in this case) and decide whether to use `Utc`, `Local`, or `Unspecified` kind on the resulting `DateTime`.  Also note that you should use `K` in the format string, not `Z`.

A better approach would be to use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`, in which case the `Z` will automatically set an offset of `+00:00`.

You'll still need to figure out what time zone to convert to, regardless of which approach you take.  If you happen to be writing code that runs on the user's device, then you get the benefit of having `TimeZoneInfo.Local` predetermined for you.  Otherwise you do not.